# Factored sparse coding: how to differentiate coordinate transform?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to implement a sparse coding technique described by Bergstra et al in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.6638v2.pdf). The encoding process there includes the following computation:

$translate(rotate(scale(\mathbf{u}, \alpha, \beta), \theta), \delta), \eta)$

where $\mathbf{u}$ is generic Gabor filter. Considering that $\mathbf{u}$ is constant, sparse coding dictionary is parametrized by transformation parameters $\{\alpha, \beta, \theta, \delta, \eta\}$. The thing I don't get is how do you compute the gradient of the transformation with respect to $\mathbf{u}$? Cosidering that the objective function is $\sum_{i}(z_{i}-u^{tr}_{i}x^{*})$, where $\mathbf{z}$ is original image and $x^{*}$ is the code (scalar, in the simple case of only one code component), is it even possible to compute such a derivative? Or am I getting something wrong here?

---

**UPDATE**

I guess my problem is that the error between an image and a rotated image seems non-differentiable to me (is it?). I'll try to illustrate it with a simpler example: suppose there's an image, that we try to approximate by another image, rotating the latter by some angle. The parameter we're trying to find is the angle, say $a$. Then, we can plot the error function $J(a)$ by rotating the original image by different angles, and it looks like this:

[image]

(0 point corresponds to rotating the original by 0 angle, which gives zero error, unsurprisingly)

But that function doesn't even look smooth (meaning it's non-differentiable), so there's no way we can find the correct $a$ value by gradient descent.

The code for that simple demonstration:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mdp
from skimage.transform import rotate


def get_gabor():
    g = mdp.utils.gabor(
        (20, 20), 0, np.pi / 2.,
        0.5, (4., .5)
    )
    return g


if __name__ == '__main__':
    orig = get_gabor()
    errs = []
    angles = []
    for a in np.linspace(-90, 90, 200):
        angles.append(a)
        rot = rotate(orig, a)
        err = np.sum((orig - rot) ** 2)
        errs.append(err)
    plt.plot(angles, errs)
    plt.show()
```

Still, I must me missing something here...

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is not differentiated with respect to u, but rather with respect to the error. There are two ways to reduce this reconstruction error: the first is by modifying u, and the second is by modifying the transformation parameters. Either or both of these can be done. Each requires back-propagating error through interpolation matrices, so it's a bit tricky in the implementation, but I'd encourage you to just work through it. It can work :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it, I guess... Yes, I'm going to optimize the objective by modifying the transformation parameters, I just don't understand how. Could you please look at my original post for the update? I tried to explain what bothers me here.